# Как корректно сгенерировать уникальный секрет TOTP

Tags: аутентификация, key

[Спецификация](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238#section-3) говорит, что для каждого пользователя необходимо сформировать уникальный секрет K. Среди предложенных вариантов мне понравился вариант с использованием совмещенных секретных ключей.
Алгоритм простой:

1. Формирую случайную строку длиной 20 байт
2. Добавляю к данной строке PIN-код

Кажется, что простая контатенация не лучший вариант, т.к. в БД будет хранится в открытом виде PIN-код пользователя. Какие можно использовать способы или алгоритмы, чтобы замешать PIN-код в строку?